# TeX doesn't see the a .sty file that is in the 2020 distribution

Tags: texlive

The file `newxtxtext.sty` has path  `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtxtext.sty`  but TeX doesn't find it.
Shouldn't it be found automatically since it is in the 2020
distribution?

I am using a system76 machine running Pop-os and installed
texlive 2020.

Comment: are you using the texlive 2020? If you use \documentclass{article} what does the log-file show for a path for article.cls?

Comment: If you look closely, you have written `newxtxtext.sty` and `newtxtext.sty`. Check your input: the correct name is the latter.

Comment: When you say “TeX doesn’t find it”, what concretely do you mean? Do you mean you get an error message when you compile a document that tries to load it? Have you tried running `kpsewhich newtxtext.sty` from the commandline/terminal, which should just check whether TeX can locate the file?